# Site not loading properly in Messenger InApp Browser not loading . Unable to debug the issue

Tags: facebook, webview, inappbrowser, messenger

I have created a website which works well on Chrome, Safari and other browsers , even on facebook in app browser. But it does not work as expected in Messenger inapp browser . I think the in app browser of facebook app and messenger app are different . I am not even able to debug the issue using Chrome://inspect tool . Chrome://inspect tool does not show anything when i load my site in messenger browser.Can anyone help here?

Comment: your question is not clear to me, can you explain more about it?
any code snippets, error logs, and such data will help

Comment: i have a simple jquery script to get data from the server and change the content in the page when i click a button . This is working well in other browsers but not in the messenger in app browser. Is there any way to find the errors in the messenger browser?